# If all divs have same style, remove element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs with the same name, I want to check if ALL divs have a style of display: none; then another div will hide too. Codepen:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/OexpgR
`

```js
jQuery(".tile").each(function () {
  if (jQuery(this).css("display") == "none") { 
    $(".hideme").hide(); 
  }
});
```

```css
.tiles {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.tile {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display: none">Test</div>
</div>
```

Jquery is only working if 1 div has this style, I want this **hideme** div to hide when ALL divs have this style

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter()` to check for `:visible` elements:

```js
function checkVisibility() {
  var allHidden = $('.tile').filter(':visible').length === 0;
  $('.hideme').toggle(!allHidden);
}

// Toggle the first element on button click and run the check
$('#toggleStyle').on('click', function() {
  $('.tile').first().toggle();
  checkVisibility();
})

checkVisibility();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggleStyle" type="button">Toggle Style</button>

<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
  <div class="tile" style="display:none">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="hideme">Hide Me!</div>
```

Comment: Can this work on a dom element? I have a filter that adds the styling

Comment: Run the above code every time the filter changes the styling

Comment: This is the code I am trying to use this in.

 var selectedClass = "";
 $(".blogfilter a").on('click', function(){
  $(".blogfilter a").removeClass("filter-selected");
  $(".tiles .tile").addClass("two-tile");
  $(this).addClass("filter-selected"); 
  selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
  $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
  $("#blog-posts .tile").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
   $("#blog-posts").fadeTo(300, 1);   
  }, 300); 
 });